# js callback gives undefined var and how defined callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have simple code:

```
<div id='temp'></div>
<div id='points'></div> 
<div onClick ="play(1, 1)" id='click'>clickclickclick</div> 


play(function (addpoints) {
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = addpoints;
}());

function play (choosecolor, randescolor) {
    if (choosecolor == randescolor) {
        if (document.getElementById('points').innerHTML === '') {
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=100;
        }
        else {
            var points = function (allpoints) {
                var addpoints = parseInt(allpoints) + 100;
                callback(addpoints);

                document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=addpoints;
            }
        }

        points(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);
    }
}
```

and I don't understand why may callback give me undefined. Console says that callback is not defined. This is strange, because it works great on simple, example code:

```
loadStuff(function (data) {
    alert('Now we have the data' + data);
});

function loadStuff (callback) {
    // Go off and make an XHR or a web worker or somehow generate some data
    var data = 'something';
    callback(data);
}
```

I think there is something that I don't know and don't understand about callback(). But what? Why it work on this second part of code, and not works correctly on the first?

Comment: You have bad formatting and I suspect you have wrong number of parens / curlies. It might be that the `play` function is defined inside another function, but it's hard to understand. Please fix formatting (try http://www.jsfiddle.com)

Comment: Why are you using an IIFE and passing the result to `play`?

Comment: Are you trying to call function `play` with the result of an inline called function (the one that accepts `addpoints`?)

Comment: What do you mean by "why may (my?) callback give me undefined"? can you explain *give me*?

Answer (score 0):

The variable named `callback` is not defined in your code, but in your last snippet, you  did have a variable `callback` as your function argument.

You need to reference the correct parameter name:

```
function play(choosecolor, randescolor){
    if(choosecolor==randescolor){
        if(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML===''){
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=100;}
        else{
            var points = function(allpoints){
                var addpoints=parseInt(allpoints)+100;
                choosecolor(addpoints); // Refer to choosecolor, not callback
                document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=addpoints;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code will get executed like this:

`play(function (addpoints) {
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = addpoints;
}());`

> An unnamed inline function, is being executed without input variable. In that context, `addpoints = undefined`. as a result the `temp` div will have the text "undefined". since the function returns nothing, play is now being called with `choosecolor = undefined, ranescolor = undefined`.

```
function play (choosecolor, randescolor) {
    if (choosecolor == randescolor) {
        if (document.getElementById('points').innerHTML === '') {
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=100;
        }
        else {
            var points = function (allpoints) {
                var addpoints = parseInt(allpoints) + 100;
                callback(addpoints);

                document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=addpoints;
            }
        }

        points(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);
    }
}
```

> function play is executed with `undefined` values for both parameters. the 1st if evaluates to true and code resumes. 2nd if also evaluates to true, and the `points` div will have the text "100". Next there is an attempt to call a function by either name of variable `points`, but since neither exists, you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

-- handle undefined ; addpoints==undefined ?'':addpoints;

```
play(function (addpoints) {
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = addpoints==undefined ?'':addpoints;
}());

function play (choosecolor, randescolor) {
    if (choosecolor == randescolor) {
        if (document.getElementById('points').innerHTML === '') {
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=100;
        }
        else {
            var points = function (allpoints) {
                var addpoints = parseInt(allpoints) + 100;
                callback(addpoints);

                document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=addpoints;
            }
        }

        points(document.getElementById('points').innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/y9uer4ge/